# Good reference for editing Qt .ui files?

Tags: qt, user-interface, markup

At times I find myself editing the XML files on Qt creator rather than using the drag and drop interface for example if I can't get my widgets in the correct row of my grid layout. Is there a good reference anywhere on how to lay UIs out using XML? For example, I'd been interested in altering the visibility of a checkbox in the XML rather than in C++ code... is this doable, or am I too much in the WPF mindset? Either way, I'd still be interested in that reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the [Qt Designer's UI File Format](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-ui-file-format.html) page useful.

I generally just use the designer to prototype something quickly, and then code it up in C++ once the design is correct. Breaking the UI up into custom widgets, rather than one massive form often produces something more manageable.

Answer (score -2):

I've been using Qt for 4 years but I never modified the UI files directly. I always do it using Qt Designer. Not sure why you ever need to modify the XML file directly.

This is not answer to your question, but I believe you're missing how to use Qt Designer. Please check [Qt Designer's Manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) first.

Comment: They are (were?) things which are done far more easily by editing the .ui manually (if you know what you're doing).

Comment: @Koying: i was thinking may be that's what the OP wants. but also thinking may be OP doesn't know much about the designer, or not comfortable with it, as he comes from WPF.

Comment: Yeah sure. Was speaking generally.